# Rails single table inheritance: type coumn is not populated automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I want to use STI in Rails 4. I already had a model `Boilerplate` and now I want to inherit a `BoilerplateOriginal` and a `BoilerplateCopy` model from it. So I added a column `type` to my table:

```
class AddTypeToBoilerplates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :boilerplates, :type, :string
    Boilerplate.update_all type: 'BoilerplateOriginal'
    change_column :boilerplates, :type, :string, null: false
  end

  def down
    remove_column :boilerplates, :type
  end
end
```

Sadly, this column doesn't seem to be filled by Rails automatically:

```
[1] a4aa2 »  x = Boilerplate.new
=> #<Boilerplate:0x00000101609580> {
               :id => nil,
            :title => nil,
             :type => nil
}
[2] a4aa2 »  x.valid?
  Boilerplate Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "boilerplates" WHERE "boilerplates"."title" IS NULL LIMIT 1
=> false
[3] a4aa2 »  x.errors
=> {
  :title => [
    [0] "must not be empty"
  ]
}
[4] a4aa2 »  x.title = 'test'
=> "test"
[5] a4aa2 »  x.valid?
  Boilerplate Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "boilerplates" WHERE "boilerplates"."title" = 'test' LIMIT 1
=> true
[6] a4aa2 »  x.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Boilerplate Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "boilerplates" WHERE "boilerplates"."title" = 'test' LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "boilerplates" ("title") VALUES (?)  [["title", "test"]]
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: boilerplates.type: INSERT INTO "boilerplates" ("title") VALUES (?)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
```

Did I miss something important? I thought Rails simply fills the column `:type` when it's available?

Comment: Yes, you are missing. `type` will be set when you will use `BoilerplateOriginal.new` or `BoilerplateCopy.new`.. That means any subclass which is a child of `Boilerplate`. But of you do `Boilerplate.new` it wouldn't set the `type` column.

Comment: @ArupRakshit post the answer, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well. You are doing it wrong of-course. The `type` column will be set, only when you will be creating the objects by using any of the child class of the parent `Boilerplate`. But if you use `Boilerplate.new`, you need to pass the `type` value manually. On the other hand, when you will do `BoilerplateCopy.new` or `BoilerplateOriginal.new`, the `type` will be set by ActiveRecord by default for you to the class name of the child class.

Read the official documentation of [Single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).

> Active Record allows inheritance by storing the name of the class in a column that by default is named `type` (can be changed by overwriting `Base.inheritance_column`). This means that an inheritance looking like this:
>
> ```
> class Company < ActiveRecord::Base; end
> class Firm < Company; end
> class Client < Company; end
> class PriorityClient < Client; end
> ```
>
> When you do `Firm.create(name: "37signals")`, this record will be saved in the companies table with `type = “Firm”`. You can then fetch this row again using `Company.where(name: '37signals').first` and it will return a `Firm` object.

Comment: Thank you! But why's that? Does this mean, STI only supports one level of inheritance and the base class is never meant to be instantiated?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim Yes. it is one level AFAIK. You can use base class, but then what is the point of using STI. Anyway, if you base class, you need to supply the `type` if you want to set it.